# Creating a class with push and pop methods in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a Python object from the class below, but when I call the method popit(), I am getting a None. Any help as to what I miss or do wrong is appreciated.

class Stack:

```
def __init__(self, *item):
    self.stack = []
def pushit(self, item):
    if len(self.stack) == 9:
        print("Stack is full: " + self.stack)
    else:
        print(self.stack.append(self.item))
        
def popit(self):
    if self.stack == []:
        print("Stack underflow: " + self.stack)
    else:
        print(self.stack.pop())
```

Comment: How could you possibly get anything *other* than a None from that method?  It doesn't contain a `return` statement at all...

Comment: Nothing changes with return. I has print function too.

Answer (score 1):

Your methods -- both of them -- don't return anything. What I would do to sort this is:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def pushit(self, item):
        if len(self.stack) == 9:
            print("Stack is full: " + self.stack)
            return None
        else:
            print(self.stack.push(self.item))
            return self.item
        
    def popit(self):
        if self.stack == []:
            print("Stack underflow: " + self.stack)
            return None
        else:
            ret = self.stack.pop()
            print(ret)
            return ret
```